# Google Maps API rendering after getting directions issue

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've got the directions to google maps, but how do I render it on the same map (the blue line that goes from one start point to a destination point), my code is a simple html as shown here : http://pastebin.com/60Rz8a5H
I've followed the tut given about v3 API by Google, but with no luck.
I'm a noob in this, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Thothathri

Answer (score 0):

You've ommitted the initializing of `directionsService` and `DirectionsDisplay`